# Cannot type in password field on safari os x

Tags: macos, twitter-bootstrap, safari, passwords

Cannot type in password field on safari, I use twitter-bootstrap for front-end.

I`m looking for a solution but I don`t find anything about this bug.

If someone have an idea about what happen please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you override the default twitter bootstrap style? If you did, then check the position, line-height, height or padding of the input. Twitter bootstrap uses border-box for [box-sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).